# I'm trying to delete all of my duplicates from my youtube Playlist but keep getting an error after a few seconds of it working,is the command wrong

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I'm trying to delete all of my duplicates from my youtube Playlist but keep getting an error after a few seconds of it working,is the command wrong. If someone could fix my command so that i also don't have to scroll down everytime for it to load more so it scrolls down after it finds everything than loads the rest of the playlist and continues? That would be a hugh help!

heres the command

```
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
function $$(selector, context = document.documentElement) {
    return [...context?.querySelectorAll?.(selector) ?? []]
};
async function removeduplicates() {
    let titles = $$("#primary a#video-title")
        .filter((i, j, k) => 
            k.findIndex(k =>
                k.href.includes(Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams(i.href))['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v'])) !== j);
    for (let i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
        titles[i].focus();
        titles[i].closest("#contents > *").querySelector('button[aria-label="Action menu"]').click();
        await sleep(100);
        var things = document.evaluate('//span[contains(text(),"Remove from")]', document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
        await sleep(300);
        for (var j = 0; j < things.snapshotLength; j++) {
            things.snapshotItem(j).click();
        }
        console.log(titles[i].innerText);
    }
}
removeduplicates();
```

and here is the error

> The resource https://i.ytimg.com/generate_204 was preloaded using link
> preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load
> event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is
> preloaded intentionally.

tried to make it able to scroll down after it finds all the duplicates songs in my Youtube Playlist than loads the rest of the playlist and continues
edit: now its giving me this error DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for https://www.youtube.com/s/desktop/6ca9d352/jsbin/web-animations-next-lite.min.vflset/web-animations-next-lite.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

Answer (score 0):

```
function scrolldown() {
  setTimeout(
    function(){
      window.scrollBy(0,1000);
      scrolldown();
    }, 1000)
}

function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
function $$(selector, context = document.documentElement) {
    return [...context?.querySelectorAll?.(selector) ?? []]
};
async function removeduplicates() {
    scrolldown()
    let titles = $$("#primary a#video-title")
        .filter((i, j, k) => 
            k.findIndex(k =>
                k.href.includes(Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams(i.href))['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v'])) !== j);
    for (let i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
        titles[i].focus();
        titles[i].closest("#contents > *").querySelector('button[aria-label="Action menu"]').click();
        await sleep(100);
        var things = document.evaluate('//span[contains(text(),"Remove from")]', document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
        await sleep(300);
        for (var j = 0; j < things.snapshotLength; j++) {
            things.snapshotItem(j).click();
        }
        console.log(titles[i].innerText);
    }
}
removeduplicates();
```

Added scrolldown() function in removeduplicates()